# Fastify cli can't connect with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, arangodb, fastify

I'm facing a problem with fastify CLI and docker. I want to create an ArangoDB database used with fastify so I created a docker-compose file like this :

docker-compose

```yaml
arangodb:
    # container_name: arangodb
    build:
      context: ./bdd
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8529:8529
    volumes:
      - ./bdd/data:/var/lib/arangodb3
      - ./bdd/apps:/var/lib/arangodb3-apps

  api:
    # container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - arangodb
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/api
      - /usr/api/node_modules
```

This is calling my api Dockerfile :

```yaml
FROM node:14.17.1

WORKDIR /usr/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

ENV DB_HOST=arangodb
ENV DB_PORT=8529
ENV DB_NAME=***
ENV DB_USER=***
ENV DB_PASS=***
ENV FASTIFY_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0                                                                                                     

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

I set FASTIFY_ADRRESS to 0.0.0.0 beacause docker expose on 0.0.0.0 as [explained here](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Getting-Started/#your-first-server).

But when I launch my docker containers with that image, arangoDb is working fine but my api return that :

> api@1.0.0 dev /usr/api
> api_1                  | > fastify start -w -l info -P -p 5000 app.js
> api_1                  |
> api_1                  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8529
> api_1                  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {

Did I miss something?

Comment: It seems your DB_HOST is ignored `ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8529` and the fastify container try the localhost

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @JohnD. look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with this api Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:14.17.1

WORKDIR /usr/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# Fastify configuration
ENV FASTIFY_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
ENV FASTIFY_PORT=5000
# DB configuration
ENV DB_HOST=http://arangodb
ENV DB_PORT=8529
ENV DB_NAME=***
ENV DB_USER=***
ENV DB_PASS=***

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

The problem was in DB_HOST configuration from arangodb to **http://arangodb**